# Algorithm in "random" elimination array

Tags: arrays

So we have this "homework" which seems to be one of those things found in Roswell, I guess. Looking for someone to help me out with this - literally any insight is priceless.

The code picks six object - each one of them contains two numbers. Then it eliminates one of the objects, and then eliminates another one from the remaining five, leaving only four of them at the end.

I have an array containing thirty nine rounds containing six objects and the result which one got deleted first and which one got deleted second. The 40th row contains only objects' values, and we need to find a pattern and assume which two objects will be deleted in the 40th round.

[Here's the link to the array in PDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KpLZYGkUNa5Oc4L06GdOD2XUViKmr13-/view?usp=drivesdk)
[and in Excel format](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HraCwX0r0KEod3Z_xztCArf6sDa34hA0/view?usp=drivesdk)

Is that even possible? Any idea on how to get started is ultra valuable.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Could you post your code which you have tried so far?

Comment: No code so far. I'm incredibly stuck, literally don't know how to start analyse these numbers and where to look for pattern.